# Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: staticfiles

Tags: python, django, heroku, web-deployment, migrate

I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm duplicating here. I'm trying to migrate my files so I can deploy on Heroku. It says that "staticfiles" is duplicated, but I can't see where the conflict is. Does migration need to be done in order to deploy? or is there something wrong with my database?

```
import dj_database_url
import os

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '.herokuapp.com']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'wiki_app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'coding_dojo_final_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'coding_dojo_final_project.wsgi.application'

...
WHITENOISE_USE_FINDERS = True

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a static root which is where Django compiles the static files for serving in production when you run `python manage.py collectstatic`. The name must be different than the location of your static files in your project.

`STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('staticfiles'))`

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#deployment) for more info.